# c# string format - cant find the right method

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I would like to `printf("%+'10d")` an integer.
Can't find the equivalent syntax for `string.Format`.
Can you help me ?

```
printf("%+'10d %+'10d %+'10d", 0, -102048224, 4865284)
```

would show:

```
    +0 -102,048,224 +4,865,284
```

However:

```
string.Format("{0,10:+#;-#;0} {1,10:+#;-#;0} {2,10:+#;-#;0}", 0, -102048224, 4865284)
```

gives (no commas, I don't care about the +0 vs 0):

```
     0 -102048224   +4865284
```

and

```
string.Format("{0,10:n0} {1,10:n0} {2,10:n0}", 0, -102048224, 4865284)
```

gives (no positive sign on the last number):

```
     0 -102,048,224  4,865,284
```

Thanks,
-Moshe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
string.Format("{0:+#,0.##;-#,0.##}     {1:+#,0.##;-#,0.##}     {2:+#,0.##;-#,0.##}", 0, -102048224, 4865284)
```

prints:

```
+0     -102,048,224     +4,865,284
```

To Align numbers to the right: (13 is arbitrary, choose whatever suits you)

```
string.Format("{0,13:+#,0.##;-#,0.##}\n{1,13:+#,0.##;-#,0.##}\n{2,13:+#,0.##;-#,0.##}", 0, -102048224, 4865284);
```

prints:

```
           +0
 -102,048,224
   +4,865,284
```

Comment: Oops... just noticed that this doesn't justify the numbers to right... any idea how to add this ?

Comment: Is there any online/offline tool to translate printf syntax to c# syntax?

Comment: @Moshe I don't think there is a tool to automatically translate these stuff. I just combined multiple c# format patterns to get the same result.